# External SMTP provider for outgoing mails in Exchange Server 2010

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, mailgun, exchange-server-2010

I would like to route all outgoing external mails via an external SMTP provider, in this case, Mailgun is my provider.

I have fiddled around with **Org -> Hub -> Send connectors** without any luck, the mails keep getting stuck and will only work if I use my standard send-connector.

Any ideas?

PS: If im in the right area, where and how can i debug the **Send connector** ? eventvwr isnt telling me much

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up the credentials. cy@